# Solve $y^{\prime\prime\prime} - 2y^{\prime\prime} - y^\prime + 2y = \frac{2x^3+x^2-4x-6}{x^4}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

First, we solve the next homogeneous differential equation $y^{\prime\prime\prime} - 2y^{\prime\prime} - y^\prime + 2y = 0$:
$\lambda^3 - 2\lambda^2 - \lambda + 2 = 0 =(\lambda-2)(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1) \Rightarrow \lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = 1,\lambda_3 = -1$.

$\therefore$ The solution is $y_h(x) = c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{x}+c_3e^{-x}$.

Now, I'm having troubles with $f(x) = \frac{2x^3+x^2-4x-6}{x^4}$, because how can I know that it has a particular form if the degree of the polynomial is negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly $$f(x) = \frac{2x^3+x^2-4x-6}{x^4}=2x^{-1}+x^{-2}-4x^{-3}-6x^{-3}=(x^{-1})'''-2(x^{-1})''-(x^{-1})'+2(x^{-1})$$
which implies $y_p=x^{-1}$ is aparticular solution.

Answer (score 2):

As the RHS is a polynomial in $x$ over $x^4$, you are tempted to try an ansatz which is a polynomial over… $x^{4-3}$. Hence plugging $\dfrac1x$ (thinking that other terms could come later), you get

$$-\frac6{x^4}-\frac4{x^3}+\frac1{x^2}+\frac2x$$

and bingo !